# Why not creating a git submodule for DTOs which will be shared across several microservices to avoid code duplication?

Tags: microservices, dto

I have some experience with monolithic applications and now I'm learning microservice architecture.

**Problem:** I noticed that we send a lot of DTOs across our microservices and that in each microservice I create a lot of DTOs which are similar to those created in other microservices and it's a lot of code duplication.

Is it a good idea to separate all the DTOs to a separate git submodule? In this case we will avoid code duplication and additionally our DTOs will always be consistent in all our microservices. Any thoughts?

Comment: At my current project, we have a shared library with all the DTOs and it works perfectly fine. However, you have to be sure that there are no breaking changes across version so there won't be an issue with several microservices having a different version of a library.

Comment: Its always a good idea to keep DTOs separate. This helps us keep the impacted area contained to particular service. Like Bohdan mentioned it's ok to do it but make sure there are no breaking changes.

Comment: This is a very common problem, and in my current project we are tackling it by creating a client wrapper which contains all the API calls with the corresponding DTOs. The calling service just imports the client jar (which contains DTOs as well) and makes the API call without having to worry about creating DTOs. We don't have a separate git submodule, but each micro service is responsible for providing a client jar for it's APIs which can be used by different services.